# append lines beginning with space to previous line

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I want to append every line in my file that begins with spaces to the previous line.

**INPUT FILE**

```
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc
 =lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad
 ,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=
 rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad
 ,dc=lan
```

**OUTPUT FILE**

```
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-epot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dmoztools.net/Computers/Programming/Languages/Awk/ can get you started with awk

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n //g' file
```

Better explained in multiline version:

```
# Define a label called 'a'
:a
# Read the next line of input and append it to the
# internal pattern buffer
N
# $ means 'the last line of input'
# ! negates the match
# ba (b)ranches back to label 'a'
# Means:
# Unless we've reached the end of the input file
# read the file line by line into the pattern buffer 
$!ba
# Once the end of the input file is reached we substitute
# every occurrence of newline+space by an empty string
s/\n //g
# sed will print the result of the substitution by default
```

---

PS: Depending on your version of `sed` you may need to use:

```
s/
 //g
```

instead of

```
s/\n //g
```

Meaning you need to use a literal newline if `\n` isn't supported

---

And btw, if your input file only contains pairs of two lines where one line has to be appended to the previous, and only that(!), then it could be as as simple as:

```
sed 'N;s/\n //' file
```

This would also not require to buffer the whole file in memory.

Comment: Basically, keep building up the buffer until you reach the last line. When you reach the last line, substitute "\n " with "//".

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions using **awk**

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n /,"")}1' file
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan

$ awk -v OFS= -v ORS= '/^ /{$NF=$NF RS}1' file
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan


$ awk -v ORS= '/^ /{ sub(/ /,""); $NF=$NF RS}1' file
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan

$ awk '/^[^ ]/{ORS=""} /^ /{OFS=""; $1=$1; ORS=RS}1' file
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
```

I would recommend 1st, 2nd and 3rd soluion.
4th one is just more verbose version of 2nd one.

There are more but I think this would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Following awk may help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/^ +/,"");printf("%s%s",$0~/^role/?(NR==1?$0:RS $0):$0,$0)} END{print ""}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{if(sub(/^ /,p,$0)) print; else p=$0}' file

roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
```

Answer (score 0):

Another **awk** approach:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s",$1,(/^ /? ORS:"") }' file
```

The output:

```
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0pe 's/\n +//g' input-file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n //;ta;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and if an appended line begins with a space, remove the preceeding newline and the space and repeat. Otherwise, print the first line in the pattern space, delete the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data you posted:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(sub(/^ /,"")?RS:"")}1' file
roleOccupant:uid=standard_rhc,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_test,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_NLHaNA,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
roleOccupant:uid=standard_dept,ou=tenants,ou=users,dc=e-depot,dc=rad,dc=lan
```

With other data YMMV so hopefully you put some thought into your sample.